# Program that displays if a given number is even or odd

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, numbers, printf

I wrote this simple code that given an input of 5 ints says if them are even or odd(I must use two arrays). But no matter what numbers I write, the output is always "5 odd.". Where am I wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int numbers[5];
int even_odd[5];

printf("%s\n", "Insert 5 numbers.");

int i;
for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    even_odd[i] = numbers[i] % 2;
    }

for(i=0; i<=4; i++);{
    if (even_odd[i] == 0){
        printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " even.");
    }else{
        printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " odd.");
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i<=4; i++);-------> Your for loop never does what it should.
{
  if (even_odd[i] == 0) {
    printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " even.");
  } else {
    printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " odd.");
  }
}
```

For loop runs 5 times and finally `i=5`, so its `even_odd[5]` which is being checked to zero.

Lucky you didn't get a crash.  C does not check for array bounds so you program ran.

Answer (score 3):

> for(i=0; i<=4; i++);{

theres a semicolon which shouldnt be there

> for(i=0; i<=4; i++){

this way

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the semicolon

```
for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
```

So your code will be like this:

```
for(i=0; i<=4; i++){   //Remove the semicolon here
    if (even_odd[i] == 0){
        printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " even.");
    }else{
        printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " odd.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`for(i=0; i<=4; i++);{`

This is where your problem lies.
You have a semicolon right after the `for` loop statement.

This translates to a loop that just increments `i` a few times.
Then you have this block of code running:

```
{
    if (even_odd[i] == 0) {
        printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " even.");
    } else {
        printf("%d%s\n", numbers[i], " odd.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the extra ; between the closing ) and the opening { in

```
for(i=0; i<=4; i++);{
```

Remove that and it will work fine.

Reason: the statement

```
    for(i=0; i<=4; i++);
```

runs just the loop and does not execute the code block following it.

After that, the code block between { and } is executed, but then i == 5 and the output will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

One basic problem is this line-

```
int i;
```

The variable should be declared not after the `printf` statement.it will be better if you declare it much before itself. `scanf` should always be the next statement after `printf` which involves taking in input.
Then you have put a semicolon after the for loop declaration.It should be like this-

```
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
```

Other than these both problems,the code is working alright.I have checked it.The output is obtained perfectly.

Comment: Why should i be declared before printf? And why should scanf be put right after printf?

Comment: In c,declarations are done much in the beginning itself. scanf is used to take up any input,so whenever a printf is given to accept an input from the keyboard there should be a scanf following it that would be there to take the input.So scanf always follows printf.The code would not work right if it is not that way.